# How to make a JS back button that ignores intra-page jumps

Tags: javascript, html, navigation

There is a javascript command, `window.history.back`, that basically undoes the last action of clicking on a link. However, it has an annoying limitation. If you are on a very large HTML page with lots of intra-page links (using the notation `<a href="#my-section">...</a>` to jump within the same page), then executing `window.back` won't get you to the previous page; it will only take you to the previous section of the same page. That's not typically what I want. Is there a way to jump to the previous page, rather than the previous section?

One approach that might work would be to record the size of the window history when you first load the page, and then go back however many additional entries have been made since then. That seems error-prone (what happens if you reload the page, for example?)

Answer (score 1):

Use window.history rather than window.back. For example, you could use the following code to create a back button:

```
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>

<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
</script>
```

Comment: That was just a typo on my part. I meant window.history.back. It undoes the last click, which takes you to the same page, if you clicked on intra-page links.